# Get gender and age with facebook graph api with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get user's gender and birthday using Facebook Graph API using Node.js. My problem is that only the user's id and name are shown and I don't know why.

This is my code until now:

Facebook.js

```
    var https = require('https');

exports.getFbData = function(accessToken, apiPath, callback) {
    var options = {
        host: 'graph.facebook.com',
        port: 443,
        path: apiPath + '?access_token=' + accessToken, //apiPath example: '/me/friends'
        method: 'GET'
    };

    var buffer = ''; //this buffer will be populated with the chunks of the data received from facebook
    var request = https.get(options, function(result){
        result.setEncoding('utf8');

        result.on('data', function(chunk){

            buffer += chunk;
        });

        result.on('end', function(){
            callback(buffer);
        });
    });

    request.on('error', function(e){
        console.log('error from facebook.getFbData: ' + e.message)
    });

    request.end();
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
 facebook.getFbData(access_token, '/me/friends', function(data){
```

This code return only the user Id and Name, how can I get his gender and age?

Comment: Are you sure that user's privacy settings allow that?

Comment: farcebook and privacy are the epitome of an oxymoron

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your method around a bit to pass in some more arguments. The path you want to request is:
`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=access_token&fields=id,name,birthday,gender`